# Charset issues when storing rss data into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, rss

At the moment I'm reading rss feeds that may be encoded in any character type, using `simplexml_load_file();`

These feeds are then looped through in php and some parts are inserted into a mysql database that is utf8 with all tables utf8 general.

When inserted into the tables I can see the ' is replaced with `â€™` and - is replaced with `â€“`

These strange characters are then shown when selected back from the table and shown in a php file.

I've tried both utf8_decode and `utf8_encode` on insert and select from the database but this doesn't help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When dealing with data in varied/unknown encodings, you need to make sure to convert the encoding to be internally consistent and take all the usual precautions to make sure your encoding doesn't screw up in any step. What exactly are you doing currently and how are you doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');` before your insert and select queries

Answer (score 0):

What is the charset and default collation set to on your the db table that you're entering data into?

**[EDIT]**

Found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#92969

> **neil art neilanddeb dort com** [17-Aug-2009 01:00](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#92969)
> Because the encoding of my XML file is UTF-8 and the
> encoding of my web page is iso-8859-1 I was getting strange characters such as â€™ instead of a right single quote.
>
> The solution to this turned out to be hard to find, but really easy to implement.
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php
>
> Using the iconv() function you can convert from one encodign to another, the TRANSLIT option seems to work best for what I needed.  Here's my example:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // convert string from utf-8 to iso8859-1
> $horoscope = iconv( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $horoscope );
> ?>
> ```
>
> I found the solution on this page...
> http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/PHP/comp.lang.php/2008-04/msg00365.html
> Hope this helps

Comment: The charset is utf8 and the collation is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$xml = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $xml);
simplexml_load_string($xml);
```